# How do I make a custom display for a jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, format, datepicker

Is it possible to show calendar as shown below using jquery datepicker.

```
                       OCT-2009
Mon      Tue     Wed     Thur     Fri        Sat    Sun
 28       29      30        1       2          3      4        
  5        6       7        8       9         10     11      
 12       13      14       15      16         17     18     
 19       20      21       22      23         24     25      
 26       27      28       29      30         31      1
```

First four dates are from previous month and the last date is from next month.
I want to generate datepicker calendar in this format only for all months.

Comment: Fixed up your ascii art.  It is better to use spaces than tabs in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

here is a plugin for you

http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: I have already added plugin but its not showing dates from previous and next month.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.selector').datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true });
```